# OkHttp client not getting custom headers from response

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I have an application A that has an endpoint which signs the response and puts the signature in a header. The header looks like:

```
X-Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
X-Signature: Zca8Myv4......PkH1E25hA=
```

When I call the application directly I see the headers.

I build application B and it's calling A via a proxy P.

Application B has an OkHttp client which sends the request and reads the response. I have a custom interceptor:

```
@Slf4j
public class SignatureValidatorInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Signature signer;

    public SignatureValidatorInterceptor(final PublicKey publicKey) {
        this.signer = getSigner(publicKey);
    }

    private static final String ALGORITHM_HEADER = "x-algorithm";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_HEADER = "x-signature";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withRSA";

    /**
     * This interceptor verifies the signature of the response
     */
    @Override
    public Response intercept(final Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

        final Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        final Headers headers = response.headers();

        log.info("Received response for url={}} with headers \n{}", response.request().url(), headers);

        final byte[] responseBodyBytes = response.peekBody(1000).bytes();

        final String algorithmHeader = headers.get(ALGORITHM_HEADER);
        final String signatureHeader = headers.get(SIGNATURE_HEADER);

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(signatureHeader) || StringUtils.isBlank(algorithmHeader)) {
            throw new Exception("No signature or algorithm header on response");
        }

        this.verifySignature(responseBodyBytes, algorithmHeader, signatureHeader);

        return response;
    }

    private void verifySignature(final byte[] responseBodyBytes, final String algorithmHeader, final String signatureHeader) {
        //code to validate signature
    }

    private Signature getSigner(final PublicKey publicKey) {
        //code to create signer
    }
}
```

The debug line logs the headers it receives. I see multiple standard http headers in my logs but I'm missing my custom headers!

I have no clue why. I first thought it was a network thing. But on doing a curl from the machine of B to application A, I see the headers are there. Also I had the proxy log the headers for me, and I can see they passed.

All applications are standard spring-boot java applications. Running on linux VM's.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Is the request succeeding with a 200 response?

Comment: Found the problem. Config was not correct on application with respect to endpoint :(. Stupid mistake.